# Perl Bing::Search Module and APPID

Tags: perl, search-engine, bing

I want to use my Perl Script to connect to Bing Search Engine and use a keyword to get search results and use them in my script.

I tried getting the Bing Developer's APPID however, all the old links do not work.

I am planning to use the [Bing::Search](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edhouston/Bing-Search-1.120270/lib/Bing/Search.pm) Perl Module from CPAN:

#### Question #1:

Is this module still good to be used with the Bing Search API?

In the CPAN Documentation it says we need to get the APPID from:

> http://www.bing.com/developers/createapp.aspx

Documentation seems to be a bit outdated.

So, I came across [this article](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/05/17/bing-developer-update-2.aspx), and it appears that some changes have been made recently and now we need to sign up at azure marketplace.

#### Question #2:

Is the above Perl Module still good for Bing Search Engine?

**Update:** I just registered on the Azure Data Marketplace and now they have provided me an AccountKey. I am not sure if it is the same as the APPID.

Also, I have subscribed to "Bing Search API – Web Results Only".

Now, it gives me options to explore the dataset.

I cannot use it with Perl Scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find [this FAQ](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_FAQ_EXT.docx) interesting, especially the *authentication* section.

Comment: ok, got it. So, AccountKeys are a replacement for APPIDs and also the Bing Search Query URL has changed, they use the OData Standard now. Which Perl Module can I use to integrate this functionality in my Perl Script?

Comment: Ok, I got it. We can write a Basic Script using WWW::Mechanize to query Bing Search API and parse the JSON Response. Thank you.

Comment: What is the Realm for the Authentication Request? The username should be blank, password is account key, but the Realm? It does not specify that.